# SDL Tridion 2013 DCP not working

Tags: 2013, dd4t, componentpresentation

I have a Dynamic CT with priority set to "high", which is used to publish a component that is present in all the pages of my website.
However, for 2013, this DCP is not displaying the changes in the website when I am publishing the component.

My website is in DD4T. Am I missing anything?

**UPDATE** - Actually the changes are getting reflected(missed before) only on the last published page even if the DCT is marked as "High". Checked the db and the comp is published using two DCT's, one is "Medium" and one "High" so all the pages should reflect the published content using the High CT instead of with the last published page.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have caching enabled in the Storage config?  Is your cache channel service configured correctly?  The cache channel service has the purpose of invalidating the cache upon publish.  Also, do you have any caching enabled in the web app?

Answer (score 3):

Might be worth making a note of the things you've tried to do to resolve this:

I'd check the following:

1. Is the DCP publishing correctly?
2. Is the updated content in the database?
3. Version of your database ?
4. Your content delivery libraries all updated correctly with your 2013 update?

Comment: Actually the changes are getting reflected(missed before) only  on the last published page even if the DCT is marked as "High". Checked the db and the comp is published using  two DCT's, one is "Medium" and one "High" so all the pages should reflect the published content instead of only last published page.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in past, there was wrong entries in the broker DB, there was an old entry always acting as latest entry, due to production restore or other logical issues. i think @Johnwinter 's #3 is referring same point.

Could you just query your broker and find out if any such issue or related  is there.
accordingly you might have to update the old entries or act as per your issue.

Comment: I have now unpublished the Medium CT and the broker has the comp with only the High DCT that is added in each page. Still my last published page is only showing the updated content.

Comment: Can you bit elaborate what you mean by updated content(medium or high). Which API are you using to access from broker via providing template tcm or priority

Comment: I have a component added with DCT(priority High) in all the pages of my website. I can see the comp presentation table that the comp is published using the High DCT and no other DCT now. Once I publish the comp after making some change it is only reflecting in the page which was last published and not in others though it has been added there as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the Dynamic component in the DB only with the High priority CT, then it might be due to caching issues that it is not reflecting on all pages. My suggestion is to try the following:

1. Check if caching is enabled and configured properly.
2. Check the DB transactions for updates to all pages.
3. Check DB transactions to see when the last page is getting published.
4. If all the above seem in correct order, check your broker DB for any improper entries that might be blocking your entry.